# how to get the device type and count using nmap

Tags: php, html, networking, nmap

is there any command to get the  device type (work stations,printers,laptop) and count of them using nmap commands?

as a example

3    work stations
5    Laptops
1    Printer
2    Servers

then once i click on work station display all workstation connected to LAN.

all results should display in a HTML Page.(im running on windows apache/PHP)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: just simple nmap commands to find all network IP and their mac,vendor,up or down) and save it as XML format and display XML result in a HTML page.bur it is not the thing i need exactly....i need to get the count and device type.i cant find any command in google.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://nmap.org/book/toc.html

Specifically this section: http://nmap.org/book/output-formats-output-to-html.html

That should at least get you started.  You may also want to investigate using Zenmap, which is the official GUI frontend for nmap: http://nmap.org/book/zenmap.html (http://nmap.org/zenmap/)

Comment: could'nt you past the answer over here and then give refs?

Comment: @brahimm What is wrong with my answer? It shows OP how to get the information they need, I am not here to do someone’s work for them.